# Remove textbox name from URL if empty

Tags: php, url, textbox

I am using a PHP website.
I have 2 text box, and both values are going through GET to next page, so it look like

http://mywebsite.com/?word=&word2=hello

I want if word is empty, don't show in the URL

like

http://mywebsite.com/?word2=hello

Please help in this..

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use some javascript prior to submitting the form to remove the form elements if they are deemed to be empty - then submitting the form.

You can write a function which is triggered by a faux-submit buttom. This validates the elements, makes changes as needed - then submits the form as the final action.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Javascript `window.location` function. 
store the values of the textbox into variable

Comment: how does this answer to question?